# Creating python list of floats from two files

Tags: python, csv

I have two files that I am going to use for plotting. one contains the x,y range and another contains data.

The following is my code to get data from one file using CSV reader.

(I have data in x,y \n format in each line of file in range.dat)

```
import csv
with open('range.dat', 'r') as f,open('data,dat','r') as d:
         reader = csv.reader(f)
         reader1 = csv.reader(d)
         for row in reader:
             print row
             x, y = map(float, row[0:2])
             print [x,y]
```

Now the problem is I also want data from `data.dat` at the same time from the same row and want to append it to [x,y] such that final list will be [x,y,data]. Is there any method through which i can iterate through `data.dat` content in same for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best would probably be to `zip` those two readers together. If you are using Python 2, you should use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to get a generator; for Python 3 you can just use `zip`.

```
for row, data in itertools.izip(reader, reader1):
    x, y = map(float, row[0:2])
    print [x,y, data]
```

Alternatively, you could also call `next` on the other reader:

```
for row in reader:
    data = next(reader1)
    ...
```

Comment: @Hima You're welcome. Note that when you use just `zip` on Python 2.x, this will read in both files at once and store their contents in a list. If the files are very big, you should rather use `izip`, which will only keep one line from each file in memory.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 but in future I am going to deal with large files containing millions of such data , so itertools.izip will make difference for me.. its better to use it from now . what do you mean by "reading files at once " in case of zip, it  just reads line by line and will return the list while itertools.izip returns the iterator right ?

Comment: @Hima Try it. Remove the `for` loop and instead do `print zip(...)`, or `print type(zip(...))`. `zip` in Python 2 will immediately read all the files and stores the content in one big list of tuples, while both `izip` and `zip` in Python 3 create a generator.